# What could be the reason for 'Error 3050008: Abort Called'

Tags: smart-contract, action, error

I'm getting the following error without any further description. What could be the issue for that?

I'm performing some binary arithmetics when calling this action, are there any known problems with that?

```
Error 3050008: Abort Called
Error Details:
abort() called
pending console output:
```

*contract compiled with eosio.cdt, deployed on kylin, using eoscanada-endpoint.*

**UPDATE**

Figured it out, reason was accessing a vector at missing index.

Comment: You should add the bit of code that caused this problem, and then right out your answer. This helps other people and it also improves search engine results for similar problems

Comment: it would be useful if the error indicated the line at which the error is being generated.  otherwise having to find the error in a long codebase is pretty painful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abort Called is usually an indicating of a segmentation violation. So look for things like:

- accessing elements of a vector or pointer
- calling new or delete on objects that have already been created or deleted
- any of the other thousands of reasons why you can get a seg fault

Comment: For me it was a cast of an empty string to uint that caused that error.